# How do I launch my app via a custom URL in an email

Tags: android, email, url

I'm adding a custom URL using the `android:scheme` in my intent filter as follows

```
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="myscheme" android:host="myhost" />
  </intent-filter>
```

I'm sending the phone an email with the following in the contents:

```
myscheme://myhost?data=whatever
```

but the above link shows up as plain text, i.e. not as a link.

Answer (score 4):

> You need to send your email in HTML,
>   with your link in an `<a>` tag:
>
> ```
> <a href='myscheme://myhost?data=whatever'>Launch
> ```
>
> App
>
> Automatic link parsing is almost
>   certainly only done with links
>   starting with `http://` or `www.`, and
>   it varies from email client to email
>   client anyway.

Ok, I tried that and it didn't work. The only solution I can offer is to actually use **`http://`** with a link going to your site, to a specific app page, with the same GET parameters. You can register an intent-filter to intercept this with the app and handle it appropriately, and if the user doesn't have the app, the web page instructs them to install it.

Comment: thanks. I tried that, but now <a href='myscheme://myhost?data=whatever'>Launch App</a> shows up in the email, as plain text

Comment: @Russell You're right, just tried it myself. In that case I'm going to have to say there's no solution.

Comment: using http will work, although it makes the user 'Complete action using' either the Browser or my app.  We must be missing something here, I don't understand why android:scheme doesn't work.

Comment: Link to your website and then redirects to "myscheme://myhost?data=whatever"

Answer (score 3):

Link to your website and then redirects to "myscheme://myhost?data=whatever"